# Securing CRUD by adding additonal layer of security(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, security, csrf, crud

So I discovered a bug in our backend where I'm able to capture access tokens which allows me to do GET POST DELETE and PUT. I'll inform our backend today on where they failed. I'm aware the traffic should be used in SSL.

Anyways, what would be the most secure way of doing CRUD when token has been stolen using Javascript? Will adding csrf make it harder? Again, I'm not saying hack-proof. I just want to make it really really hard for an attacker to become successful in his attack.

Or how would you make the token unusable?

Comment: Nothing you do with JavaScript will make any difference at all to the difficulty of gaining illicit access to the server.

Comment: Ok, not unless everytime a user makes a POST, he enters a value like an RSA token that will be tested against an ACE server. However, it will make the application so expensive especially it's a web application. Thanks.

Comment: what is your threat model? who/what/where/how?